# D3.js Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have D3.js barchart published in IIS however,  calling d3.csv function causes the following error:

```
GET http://localhost/D3JS/barchartCopy/Shipping.csv 406 (Not Acceptable)
```

this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         d3.csv('http://localhost/D3JS/barchartCopy/Shipping.csv', function(data) {
    render(data);
    });
```

has anyone come across something like this?!

**Edit:**

I think the issue is related to some Http header, that should be included in function call!

Comment: A 406 response means that the server is refusing to provide the content you've asked for. Have you configured IIS to allow serving CSV files? In any case, this is a server configuration issue, not a JS/D3 one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to
[Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan)!
you brought my attention to IIS.

I need to change the MIME Types in the application node in IIS.

> IIS --> website --> MIME Types
>
> change .csv MIME Type from --> application/octet-stream to -->
> text/csv

Reload the application pool.

and this fixed the issue.